# How does iterm2 work?

Tags: iterm

I am curious how does [iterm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) work? I mean it would be a gargantuan task to re-implement all the unix commands and I guess it somehow uses the built-in terminal under the covers to run the actual commands but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both applications: built-in Apple Terminal and iTerm2 are only [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). They do not implement any commands, they just take care of the display.

When you open either a Terminal or an iTerm2 window, it automatically runs a [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) (like [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) or [ksh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell)). This is the program that interprets most of the commands that you know as CLI. When you type a command into a shell, it first tries to match it with its internal set of commands and interprets it accordingly. If a command is not found, the shell will try to find a program which name matches the command. This is what you might perceive aa "unix commands", however they are just standalone programs.

For example: If you run a Terminal on a Mac, it runs bash shell by default. Then if you type `date`, the shell will find it is not an internal shell command, so it will search the disk (it will search only in places defined in a so called "PATH environment variable") and it will most likely find a program in the following place `/bin/date`. The shell will execute this program. The Terminal will then print the standard output of the `date` command in its window.

iTerm2 does not use Terminal in the background, but it will run the same shell. So the flow is: iTerm2 runs bash (by default), bash then executes a `date` command and `date` command will send its output to the iTerm2 which will display the characters for the user.

Comment: thanks. so how does one go about writing their own emulator? how are all the bash and unix commands accessed in a programming language like C, C++ etc.?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/black-screen/black-screen is an example of a new terminal emulator recently getting traction. You can see how it is being actively developed. bash commands can only be executed by calling bash program and passing a script with commands to it. Other external commands can be called either from this script or on their own.

Comment: This is not really a Mac-specific question, so you find more information on StackOverflow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094242/how-can-i-call-bash-from-c-with-a-clean-environment